# flutter<->android communication expense

Tags: android, flutter, communication, flutter-platform-channel

I'm adapting an existing Android project to Flutter and I'd like to get some advice regarding **performance in flutter<->android communication**. We do image processing in real time from the camera thus performance is essential.

I know I will keep some of the features in the native side because there is no plugin that can do them. However, I have plenty of other small tasks that need information from these features and can easily be built in dart.

I'd like to understand how big of an impact has the share of information using **invoke method** in the overall performance of the app. I'd like to understand if I might be better off simple doing these operations in the native side and avoid huge amounts of info being transmitted between flutter and android.

I've tried measuring performance simply by wrapping invokeMethod between the following, but I'm not sure if this is the best way of assessing that.

```
long time1 = System.nanoTime();
methodChannel.invokeMethod("myFloatArray", coordsList);
System.out.println("time to invoke: "+(System.nanoTime()-time1));
```

Say that I need to send one ArrayList with 10 Floats 30 times per second.
**What would be the best way to measure the computational expense of this?** Would I be better off with eventChannel instead of method? If you could provide me some links to what happens "under the hood" when doing the invoke method I'd be appreaciated too!

Thank you!